# I am having trouble posting my app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I am using this video to push my messaging app on Heroku: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJzbJQLGehs

The server I am trying to push is in this repository: https://github.com/devonasmus/server/tree/masterbranch

When I try to push the server on Heroku, I get this error:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
engines.node (package.json): unspecified
engines.npm (package.json): unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version 18.x...
   Downloading and installing node 18.13.0...
   Using default npm version: 8.19.3
-----> Installing dependencies
Installing node modules (package.json)
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: server@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: stream-chat@4.4.3
npm ERR! node_modules/stream-chat
npm ERR! stream-chat@"^4.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer stream-chat@"^7.1.0" from stream-chat-react@9.5.2
npm ERR! node_modules/stream-chat-react
npm ERR! stream-chat-react@"^9.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.gkAsi/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.gkAsi/_logs/2023-01-24T22_49_58_935Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed

   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   Some possible problems:
   
   - Node version not specified in package.json
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
   
   Love,
   Heroku
! Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
! Push failed
```

I have tried changing the package.json file. I have tried using github instead of Heroku cli. I have searched all over google and stackoverflow. I have even contacted the Heroku help desk. And nothing is working so far.

Comment: Suggestion: specify your node version in package.json, make sure it's one Heroku supports, install dependencies, check in the lockfile, push again.

Comment: I have specified my node version in my package.json file.